# Back Key doesn't terminate the app and doesn't back to mai page

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm working in a Windows Phone 8.1 Project and have created it from a WP blank page (XAML and C#). After that added a new blank page and I navigate from main page through a blank page using a button. Now I'm struggling to navigate between pages.

If I'm at main page and press the physical back key button of my cellphone, my app doesn't terminate, instead it goes to background.

If I'm at blank page and press the physical back key button of my cellphone, my app doesn't go back to main page, instead it goes to background.

I have tried several methods from internet (most of them using silverlight which is not my case) but I didn't understand how to create an event handler to deal with that.

Comment: The back key does not terminate a WP8.1 XAML project, this is clearly stated in the docs.

Comment: What does your navigation command on the button look like?

Answer (score 0):

Navigation doesn't work in 8.1 because it isn't built in by default as it was in 8.0. You either have to do it yourself or instead of using a new Blank Page use a Basic Page.

The first time you add a Basic Page to your project the IDE will automagically add all the stuff to do automatic back page navigation. It will add a new NavigationHelper class under the Common directory. It will also add NavigationHelper methods to the page where you can add code for recreating the page after a terminate and resume.